# My car intermittently won't crank

Tags: starting, car

Have a 2001 grand prix gt 3800 v6 and it's started intermittently doing nothing when I turn the key usually right after I come out of a store or stop somewhere then get back in . I turn the key and nothing no sound and then after a few minutes in cranks up as usual.  So far it's only happened after I drive it to the store or something. When I go out in morning or after it's sat it always cranks . It did it a few times about a month ago then stopped for a while and in last few days it's started doing it again. What could this be ? 90% of time it cranks right up no problem.  Input is appreciated,  thank you.

Comment: My first check would be the crankshaft sensor, that was my fix with the same issue, could be the ignition control module on the heat sink too though

Answer (score 1):

I suspect when the engine heats, things expand. Depending on how old your battery is, it may not have the cranking amps necessary to turn over a hot engine. Have your battery checked out first, then look to issues with the rest of your starting system - starter, solenoid, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a solenoid/relay thats dying. Check main relay and such.

Your starter might be dying. Get a hammer and tap on the starter and try again. If this works, then replace starter.

Might be the heat is making your wiring or something related to the electricals disconnect intermittently due to thermal expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are most likely but the fuse board in modern cars dies slowly and intermittently to allow you to get to a garage and get things fixed also.